# Best practice for adding a new item in client

Tags: django, reactjs, design-patterns

I have a list that the client fetches from the server.
The client can add more items, and it's 'auto save' so no need to press a button.
My question is how to manage the new item id (can be several).
Do I need to immediately go to the server to get a new key? or can I allocate some key Ids (say 0-10) and later in the auto save call the server will know to assign new keys and notify the client?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I've been in a situation similar to yours and what I found to be a good solution was to optimistically adding the new item to the list with a uuid (generated with a library like [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)), which was used as both a temporary item id and the `key` for the react element, then when I get the 201 response from the server I update it with the actual id.

The catch here is edits and deletions while the item is still not persisted on the server. You can save yourself the hassle of dealing with that by simply disabling these options until the server responds.